# Windows IoT Raspberry Pi 3 c# Audio Playback in Different Pages

Tags: c#, audio, raspberry-pi3, audio-player, windows-iot-core-10

I am making an app on Rasp Pi 3 where I can trigger a button on "Playback Page" to activate an audio playback using MediaPlayer in a page. Once I switch to another page, the audio will remain playing in the background but once I navigate back to the "Playback Page" the audio is still playing but i lost control of the MediaPlayer due to my mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(); line. if it's on repeat mode I can't stop playing & if i trigger another message, both new & existing message will play concurrently.

How do I ensure that there is only one MediaPlayer playing at a time even when I switch between pages.
Please help. Thank you.

Edited code:

```
public sealed partial class MessagePage : Page
{

   private object syncObj = new object();

   public MessagePage()
       {
           this.InitializeComponent();
           startclock();

           this.Home.Click += Home_Click;
           this.Message.Click += Message_Click;

           //mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
           mediaPlayer = this.GetInstance();

           //mediaPlayer.MediaEnded += MediaPlayer_MediaEnded;
           //mediaPlayer.MediaOpened += MediaPlayer_MediaOpened;
       }

    public MediaPlayer GetInstance()
       {
           lock (syncObj)
           {
               if (mediaPlayer == null)
               {
                   mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                   mediaPlayer.MediaEnded += MediaPlayer_MediaEnded;
                   mediaPlayer.MediaOpened += MediaPlayer_MediaOpened;
               }
           }

           return mediaPlayer;
       }
   }
```

Old code:

```
public MessagePage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        startclock();

        this.Home.Click += Home_Click;
        this.Message.Click += Message_Click;

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.MediaEnded += MediaPlayer_MediaEnded;

    }

private async void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StorageFolder externalDevices = KnownFolders.RemovableDevices;
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> externalDrives = await externalDevices.GetFoldersAsync();
        StorageFolder usbStorage = externalDrives[0];

        if (usbStorage != null)
        {
            StorageFolder storageFolder = KnownFolders.RemovableDevices;
            StorageFile audioFile = await usbStorage.GetFileAsync("message1.mp3");
            mediaPlayer.Source = Windows.Media.Core.MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(audioFile);
            mediaPlayer.Play();
            TextBlock.Text = "Playing Message 1...";
        }
        else
        {
            TextBlock.Text = "No USB Storage Detected...";
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [singleton pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) here.The singleton pattern is a software design pattern that restricts the instantiation of a class to one object. This is useful when exactly one object is needed to coordinate actions across the system.

```
    private static readonly object syncObj = new object(); 

    public MediaPlayer GetInstance()
    {
        lock (syncObj)
        {
            if (mediaPlayer == null)
            {
                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mediaPlayer.MediaEnded += MediaPlayer_MediaEnded;
            }
        }

        return mediaPlayer;
    }
```

> ```
>     public MessagePage()
>     {
>         this.InitializeComponent();
>         startclock();
>
>         this.Home.Click += Home_Click;
>         this.Message.Click += Message_Click;
>
>         //mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
>         mediaPlayer = this.GetInstance();
>
>     }
> ```

Comment: Thanks. I will try that out. I am curious that does using pivot give almost the same result that the mediaplayer declaration won't cost conflict like my case?

Comment: Hi I ran the code & as i click the button to the page, it ran into "exception User-Unhandled" where lock(syncobj) - value cannot be null. I don't understand.

Comment: Hi mylim, syncObj should be new an object.

Comment: yes.. i did declare as new object. I posted my code below. I really can't understand what is wrong.

Comment: I think you need to check wheather your message1.mp3 file does exist in your storage. I test the code and it's ok. Please make sure the usb storage and media file got correctly. Feel free to let me know there is any question.

Comment: Hi Micheal, yes the file is in my USB drive. I re-typed the code & i don't get the exception handler prompt anymore. I could play the .mp3 files with no issue. However, I still can't gain control of the mediaPlayer when I switch to HOME & back to MESSAGE. . can advise? thanks.

Comment: Hi mylim,I tested that navigating from HOME page to MESSAGE page, in MESSAGE page, click Play button to play a mp3,and go back to HOME page, the audio is still playing,then I navigate to MESSAGE page again, click Pause button, the audio is paused.Does it conform your anticipate？

Comment: Hi Micheal, that's not what I encountered. It's just back to square one.. is there anything that I need to make reference to or any other setup need to be done?