# Windows IoT Raspberry Pi 3 c# writing app with Pivot or Pages

Tags: c#, xaml, pivot, raspberry-pi3, windows-iot-core-10

I am fairly new to this. I am still figuring out and to understand what type of XAML UI I should adopt or best suited for my application.

my requirements are:

- have a few tabs to contain separate operation functions respectively
- all the functions are working concurrently
- tabs are HOME (home screen displaying time & date etc), MESSAGE (to play selected message from AppButton or GPIO), RECORDING (to record and playback audio from Appbutton or GPIO) , LOG(to access & display log details)

I have tried working on multi Page but I keep running into issue when i switch between pages ([Audio playback in different Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46381369/windows-iot-raspberry-pi-3-c-sharp-audio-playback-in-different-pages/46403123#46403123).

So I tried pivot referring to UWP Pivot example from GitHub. I kept getting Invalid Markup when I try to insert an image (icon) for each of the pivot. Is there any other example that I could refer to because I have been searching on the web but couldn't find any more detailed example. The icon I need was simple which uses the standard windows icon similar to those available for AppBarButton.

Please advise.

UPDATED
Below are the 'invalid markup' i encounter and error with System namespace

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you referred [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlPivot)? How do you insert an image?

Comment: This is the sample i was referring to. Once I load into VS it shows invalid markup on the xaml.

Comment: Do you mean you load the sample without any modifications? What's your Visual Studio version?

Comment: Hi Rita, yes without modification. I am using VS2017 community edition.

Comment: Restart your PC and clone the newest sample from github and try again.

Comment: Hi Rita, it doesn't seem to work. I have attached printscreen of the invalid markup and invalid namespace i encountered. I didn't modify the code.

Comment: Firstly try cleaning and rebuilding, the references are supposed to be pulled down by NuGet. If not working, then follow the steps [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9b3b8c2b-8558-4f37-9103-60bfb87ad942/uwpunable-to-build-windows-universal-samples-with-rtm?forum=wpdevelop).